# Canonical name for every Unicode character

Tags: python, unicode

```
>>> from unicodedata import name, lookup
>>> name('a')
'LATIN SMALL LETTER A'
>>> name('☃')
'SNOWMAN'
>>> name('A')
'LATIN CAPITAL LETTER A'
>>> name('`')
'GRAVE ACCENT'
>>> name('☹')
'WHITE FROWNING FACE'
>>> name('☺')
'WHITE SMILING FACE'
```

I know that Unicode is the correspondence between characters and Integers.

UTF-8 is the correspondence between numbers and bytes. Python follows UTF-8 encoding.

But,

What is the usage of canonical name in programming? Is it specific to python?

```
U+263a WHITE SMILING FACE
U+2639 WHITE FROWNING FACE
```

Answer (score 3):

No, it is not specific to Python. Those are the names given to the code points by the Unicode standard.

Comment: What is the purpose of canonical names? Does Java support canonical name?

Comment: (a) I'm not sure, but I believe it's to give people talking about Unicode a jargon that they can use rather than, in spoken and written English, referring to characters only by numbers (that don't mean anything until you look them up) or using the glyphs themselves in print (which are ambiguous due to homoglyphs, reliant on font support, and it's often impossible to look up ones you don't recognise yourself). (b) I have no idea whether there's anything that ships with Java, but ICU4J includes methods `UCharacter.getName` and `getCharFromName`.

Answer (score 1):

As another answer mentioned already, **no, they are not specific to Python**. They are names for Unicode characters set by the [Unicode Consortium](http://unicode.org). You can see the names of characters in the [character charts](http://www.unicode.org/charts/) on their website. The [Python docs](https://docs.python.org/) also have a [page](https://docs.python.org/2/howto/unicode.html) about Unicode.